# Fetch distinct results from a table having one to many relationship

Tags: java, mysql, sql, one-to-many

Table structure:

Table A

> id name qty....

Table B

> id a_id ...

sql:

```
select sum(a.qty)
from A a inner join B b on a.id=b.a_id;
```

Now I need to get the sum of qty column. but which is giving duplicate values.
I know it can be done by inner query. But need to get the same in single query.

Here, B has many to one relationship with A. So, in the sql query: 
select a.* from A a inner join B b on a.id=b.a_id gives me duplicate results of A. I am trying to get distinct results of A in a single query

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: I fail to understand what you mean by *duplicate values*. Can you please give a concrete example?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would more effectively convey what you are trying to do.

Comment: Here, B has many to one relationship with A.
So, in the sql query:
select a.* from A a inner join B b on a.id=b.a_id
gives me duplicate results of A.

Comment: Listen to @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks equivalent to simply:

```
select  a_id
,       sum(qty) qty
from    B
group by a_id
```

I'm guessing you want more data from `a`, in which case use:

```
select     a.id
,          b.qty
from       A a 
inner join (
             select  a_id
             ,       sum(qty) qty
             from    B
             group by a_id
           ) b 
      on   a.id=b.a_id
group by   a.id
```

Remember, every attribute in the select should be either in an aggregate function, or in the `group by`. `mysql` allows it if you don't, but it's wrong.

Comment: Here, B has many to one relationship with A.
So, in the sql query:
select a.* from A a inner join B b on a.id=b.a_id
gives me duplicate results of A. I am trying to get distinct results of A in a single query

Comment: My second query shouldn't give duplicates, since we `group by` `B.a_id`. I'll reiterate, because `mysql` is weird in aggregates: every selected attribute has to be either in an aggregate function (`sum`, `max` etc) or in a `group by`!